# Менять стилизацию компонента пропсами или css переменными?

Tags: css, reactjs

У меня есть компонент и при определённых брейкпоинтах нужно менять его стилизацию.
Я вижу 2 возможных, вроде как плюс минус нормальных варианта, но пока не могу понять у какого больше удобства.

1. через пропсы :

```js
<InfoBlock
  options={{
    iconWidth: 100,
    iconMargin: 50,
    color: 'red',
    breakpoints: {
      991: {
        iconWidth: 50,
        iconMargin: 25
      },
      767: {
        iconWidth: 20,
        color: 'brown'
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

т.е. при таком раскладе я по сути внутри самого компонента крутить полученные пропсы как угодно и изменять что необходимо.

2. изменять стилизацию компонента через css переменные

```css
.info-block {
  --icon-width: 100px;
  --icon-margin: 50px;
  --color: red;

  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    --icon-width: 50px;
    --icon-margin: 25px;
  }

  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    --icon-width: 20px;
    --color: brown;
  }
}
```

```html
<InfoBlock className="info-block"/>
```

Оба варианта рабочие, и не знаю, стоит ли изменение css свойств запихивать в пропсы, хотелось услышать мнение ещё кого-то по этому поводу.

Comment: Я за вариант css. По крайней мере, если потребуется сменить стили, не потребуется шерстить код компонентов и прочее.